# Seeing the number of cpu instructions a Python/C script send

Tags: python, c, profiling, cpu

Is it possible to see how many CPU instruction a Python/C script send? I want to do it both on Windows and Linux with programs doing essentially the same thing, but one written in C and one in Python. How can I achieve this?

I know there are some profiling tools in Python, but they only tell how many times Python functions are implemented as far as I understand.